# Why my tensorflow agent's training gets slower? is it because my batch feeding strategy?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, training-data

I'm trying to solve the 'BipedalWalker-v2' problem from Open AI, by using python and Tensorflow. In order to solve it I'm implementing an episodic policy gradient algorithms. Because the 'BipedalWalker-v2' actions are continuous my policy is approximated by a multivariate Gaussian distribution. The mean of this distribution is approximated using a fully connected neural network. My neural network has the following layers: [input:24,hidden:5,hidden:5,output:4]. My problem is that when I train the agent, the training process gets slower and slower until it almost freeze. My guess is that I'm misusing sess.run, I'm not feeding the batches in an efficient way. But is just a guess. My question is: Is my guess correct? if it is correct, how can I improve it? and if it is something else, what it is? I'm not looking for a literal solution I just want to get some lights about how to improve the training.

*Thanks in advance,*

#### my computer is a Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming, GeForce nvidia gtx 1050, 8 gb ram,cpu: I5

## My CODE:

### Libraries:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
import numpy as np
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

### Agent class:

```
class agent_episodic_continuous_action():
    def __init__(self, lr, s_size,a_size,batch_size,dist_type):

        self.stuck = False
        self.gamma = 0.99
        self.dist_type = dist_type
        self.is_brain_present = False
        self.s_size = s_size
        self.batch_size=batch_size
        self.state_in= tf.placeholder(shape=[None,s_size],dtype=tf.float32)
        self.a_size=a_size
        self.reward_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=[None],dtype=tf.float32)
        self.cov = tf.eye(a_size)
        self.reduction = 0.01
        if a_size > 1:
            self.action_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,a_size],dtype=tf.float32)
        else:
            self.action_holder = tf.placeholder(shape=[None],dtype=tf.float32)

        self.gradient_holders = []
        self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr)

    def save_model(self,path,sess):
        self.saver.save(sess, path)


    def load_model(self,path,sess):
        self.saver.restore(sess, path)

    def create_brain(self,hidd_layer,hidd_layer_act_fn,output_act_fn):

        self.is_brain_present =  True
        hidden_output=slim.stack(self.state_in,slim.fully_connected,hidd_layer,activation_fn=hidd_layer_act_fn)
        self.output = slim.fully_connected(hidden_output,self.a_size,activation_fn=output_act_fn,biases_initializer=None)

    def create_pi_dist(self):

        if self.dist_type == "normal":
         #   amplify= tf.pow(slim.fully_connected(self.output,1,activation_fn=None,biases_initializer=None),2)
            mean= self.output
            #cov =tf.eye(self.a_size,batch_shape=[self.batch_size])*amplify
            normal = tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalFullCovariance(
                 loc=mean,
                 covariance_matrix=self.cov*self.reduction)  
            self.dist = normal  

    def create_loss(self):

        self.loss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.log(self.dist.prob(self.action_holder))*self.reward_holder)

    def get_gradients_holder(self):

            for idx,var in enumerate(self.tvars):
            placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name=str(idx)+'_holder')
            self.gradient_holders.append(placeholder)

    def sample_action(self,sess,state):

        sample_action= sess.run(self.dist.sample(),feed_dict={self.state_in:state})       
        return sample_action

    def calculate_loss_gradient(self):
        self.gradients = tf.gradients(self.loss,self.tvars)


    def update_weights(self):
        self.update_batch = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(self.gradients,self.tvars))

        return self.update_batch

    def memorize_data(self,episode,first):
        if first:
            self.episode_history = episode
            self.stuck = False
        else:
            self.episode_history = np.vstack((self.episode_history,episode))




    def shuffle_memories(self):
        np.random.shuffle(self.episode_history)

    def create_graph_connections(self):
        if self.is_brain_present:
            self.create_pi_dist()
            self.create_loss()
            self.tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
            self.calculate_loss_gradient()
            self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
            self.update_weights()
        else:
            print("initialize brain first")

        self.init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    def memory_batch_generator(self):

        total=self.episode_history.shape[0]

        amount_of_batches= int(total/self.batch_size)    
        for i in range(amount_of_batches+1):

            if i < amount_of_batches:
                top=(i+1)*self.batch_size
                bottom =i*self.batch_size 
                yield (self.episode_history[bottom:top,0:self.s_size],self.episode_history[bottom:top,self.s_size:self.s_size+self.a_size],self.episode_history[bottom:top,self.s_size+self.a_size:self.s_size+self.a_size+1],self.episode_history[bottom:top,self.s_size+self.a_size+1:])
            else:
                yield (self.episode_history[top:,0:self.s_size],self.episode_history[top:,self.s_size:self.s_size+self.a_size],self.episode_history[top:,self.s_size+self.a_size:self.s_size+self.a_size+1],self.episode_history[top:,self.s_size+self.a_size+1:])

    def train_with_current_memories(self,sess):
        self.sess = sess
        for step_sample_batch in self.memory_batch_generator():

             sess.run(self.update_weights(), feed_dict={self.state_in:step_sample_batch[0],self.action_holder:step_sample_batch[1],self.reward_holder:step_sample_batch[2].reshape([step_sample_batch[2].shape[0]])})

    def get_returns(self):

        self.episode_history[:,self.s_size+self.a_size:self.s_size+self.a_size+1] = self.discount_rewards(self.episode_history[:,self.s_size+self.a_size:self.s_size+self.a_size+1])


    def discount_rewards(self,r):
        """ take 1D float array of rewards and compute discounted reward """
        discounted_r = np.zeros_like(r)
        running_add = 0
        for t in reversed(range(0, r.size)):
            running_add = running_add * self.gamma + r[t]
            discounted_r[t] = running_add 
        return discounted_r   

    def prob_action(self,sess,action,state):

        prob = sess.run(self.dist.prob(action),feed_dict={self.state_in:state})
        return prob

    def check_movement(self):

        ep_back = 5
        jump = 3
        threshold = 3
        if len(self.episode_history) > ep_back*2:
            difference = sum(abs(self.episode_history[-ep_back:-1,:]-self.episode_history[-ep_back-jump:-1-jump,:]).flatten())
            print(difference)
            if difference < threshold:
                self.stuck = True

    def print_last_n_returns(self,n):

        if len(self.episode_history[:,self.s_size+self.a_size:self.s_size+self.a_size+1])>n:
            n_returns = sum(self.episode_history[-n:,self.s_size+self.a_size:self.s_size+self.a_size+1])/float(n)
            print(n_returns)
            return n_returns
```

### Training loops:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
agent_2= agent_episodic_continuous_action(1e-2,s_size=24,a_size=4,batch_size=30,dist_type="normal")

agent_2.create_brain([5,5],tf.nn.relu,None)

agent_2.create_graph_connections()


env = gym.make('BipedalWalker-v2')
with tf.Session() as sess:             

    sess.run(agent_2.init)
    for i in range(200):

        s = env.reset()
        d = False
        a=agent_2.sample_action(sess,[s])[0]

        print(a)

        if None in a:
            print("None in a! inside for")
            print(s)

        s1,r,d,_ = env.step(a)
        episode = np.hstack((s,a,r,s1))
        agent_2.memorize_data(episode=episode,first=True)
        count = 0 
        while not d:
            count = count + 1
            s = s1
            a=agent_2.sample_action(sess,[s])[0]
            s1,r,d,_ = env.step(a)
            episode = np.hstack((s,a,r,s1))
           # env.render()
            agent_2.memorize_data(episode=episode,first=False)
           # print(s1)
            if count % 5 == 0 :
                agent_2.check_movement()
            if agent_2.stuck:
                d = True

        agent_2.get_returns()
        agent_2.print_last_n_returns(20)
        agent_2.shuffle_memories()
        agent_2.train_with_current_memories(sess)

env.close()
```

For each batch of 30 samples I execute Agent.update_weights()

```
   def update_weights(self):
        self.update_batch = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(self.gradients,self.tvars))
```

When I execute:

```
def train_with_current_memories(self,sess):
    self.sess = sess
    for step_sample_batch in self.memory_batch_generator():
        sess.run(self.update_weights(), feed_dict={self.state_in:step_sample_batch[0],self.action_holder:step_sample_batch[1],self.reward_holder:step_sample_batch[2].reshape([step_sample_batch[2].shape[0]])})
```

Or maybe this sluggishness is an expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The code was slowing down after each iteration because the graph was getting bigger at each iteration. This is because I was creating new graph elements inside the iteration loop.

during each iteration the following function was being called:

```
def update_weights(self):
        self.update_batch = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(self.gradients,self.tvars))    
        return self.update_batch
```

This function was creating a new element to the graph.

The best way to avoid "graph leaking" is to add the line

```
sess.graph.finalize()
```

as soon as you create your session. In this way, if there is a graph leaking, Tensorflow will raise an exception.